# How to Change Combobox Background Color while Clicked(ComboBox is Open) in WPF?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox, background-color

Can anybody knows,

How to Change Combobox Background Color while Clicked(ComboBox is Open) in WPF?

Comment: Can you tell us what language or framework you're using?

Comment: what programming language?

Comment: Hello, It's WPF (.Net)

Comment: When you say "Clicked(ComboBox is Open)" I assume you mean mean the combobox's dropdown is open? (This doesn't necessarily have anything to do with being clicked. You can move the keyboard focus into a ComboBox with, e.g., Tab, and then type F4 to open it too.) But if you mean something other than the dropdown, please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly naive approach:

```
<ComboBox
  ItemsSource="{x:Static Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}"
  Width="100"
  >
  <ComboBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

Initially, this sets the `Background` property to `Green`, but arranges for it to go to `Red` when the drop-down appears. However, there are two problems with this:

1. In some Windows themes (e.g., the Aero theme used in Vista and Windows 7), the green background gets obscured by the bluish colour that theme uses to indicate that the dropdown's button has been pressed. So the button will briefly go green before fading to Cyan.
2. The `ComboBox.Background` property only affects the appearance of the button itself, and not the dropdown list. It's possible that what you actually want to do is change the background colour of the part that pops down.

If 2 is what you wanted, this does the trick:

```
<ComboBox
  ItemsSource="{x:Static Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}"
  Width="100"      >
  <ComboBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
       <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
    </Style>
  </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

Strictly speaking, that's actually changing the background colour of the `ComboBoxItem` controls that appear in the dropdown but that will have the desired effect.

If you want to fix 1, though, you'll need a custom templates, because the built-in `ComboBox` template doesn't really provide very good support for the `Background` property, because it changes the colour of the button part under various circumstances. The Aero theme's look for a `ComboBox` really isn't designed to support a custom background colour, so you'd need to create your own custom look for the control.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, to answer your question for code behind:

Add Items to your Combo box:

```
foreach (String tag in tags)
{
    ComboBoxItem item = new ComboBoxItem();
    item.Content = tag;
    cbTags.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Then you can modify the items background color:

```
((ComboBox)o).Background = GetBrushByRGB(r, g, b);
foreach (ComboBoxItem item in ((ComboBox)o).Items)
{
    item.Background = GetBrushByRGB(r, g, b);
}
```

So basically you need to change the ComboBoxItem's backcolor.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get the default template for the Combobox (details below if you need them). Then, put this XAML inside the first "ControlTemplate.Triggers" tag:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="Red"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Your combobox button will be Red when the dropdown is open.

To get the default template: In Visual Studio 2015, view your page in Design mode. Then, right-click on the combobox, and choose "Edit Template->Edit a Copy". This will generate the default template for you.